# Summing the child values of a self referencing parent/child list and setting the parents to the sum

Tags: javascript, java, c#

I have a list of product entities that are self referencing and can go infinite levels. For example:

```
Name: Product 1
Parent: null
Value: null

Name: Product 2
Parent: "Product 1"
Value: 20

Name: Product 3
Parent: "Product 2"
Value: null

Name: Product 4
Parent: "Product 3"
Value: 40

Name: Product 5
Parent: "Product 4"
Value: 50

Name: Product 6
Parent: null
Value: null

Name: Product 7
Parent "Product 6"
Value: 30
```

I am attempting to set any entity that has a null value with the sum of all of the entities below that entity if any of the have values. In the example above I would end up with:

```
Name: Product 1
Parent: null
Value: 110

Name: Product 2
Parent: "Product 1"
Value: 20

Name: Product 3
Parent: "Product 2"
Value: 90

Name: Product 4
Parent: "Product 3"
Value: 40

Name: Product 5
Parent: "Product 4"
Value: 50

Name: Product 6
Parent: null
Value: 30

Name: Product 7
Parent "Product 6"
Value: 30
```

I have tried to do a bit of preprocessing, storing the entities in a hashmap but have not been successful.

Comment: Can you show us the data in any of the three languages you tagged?

Comment: Seems like a `Set` to track if the object has already been visited should work.

Comment: Which language are you using, please tag only one. If you want a generic algorithm, please tag [tag:language-agnostic]

Answer (score 1):

Transform this flat hierarchy into a true hierarchy and recurse.

```
public class Node {
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public int Value {get; set;}
  public List<Node> Children = new List<Children>();
}

public int Sum(Node node) {
  int sum = 0;

  foreach(var childnode in node.Children) {
    sum+= Sum(childnode);
  }
  sum+= node.Value
  return sum;
}

//store all nodes
var Nodes = new List<Node>();
foreach(var node in Nodes) {
  if (node.Value = 0) {
   node.Value = Sum(node);
  }
}
```

Comment: you're going to iterate twice, it is possible to do this with a single pass

Comment: What's the point of checking if there are more than 0 child nodes before the foreach loop? It doesn't guard against Children being null. If there are 0 children, the foreach loop will execute 0 times, which is perfectly harmless. Is it just to make the code more verbose?

Comment: yes nice remark @David Conrad.

Comment: @Hazrelle I was wrong about it, removed it now